# Velocity: First argument (undefined) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, velocity

I'm trying to build a website and I want to animate some pictures in a gallery using Velocity.

This is the most simplified version of the code I'm trying to use, because linking it to a mouseenter event doesn't throw any errors but it doesn't work either.

```
  $( this ).velocity({
    "translateZ": "200px"
  })
```

The error it's giving me is

> Velocity: First argument (undefined) was not a property map, a known action, or a registered redirect.

I'm not very good at this but I've done this before on a school project and now not even pasting that code in my current project is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check what your $(this) returns, console log it. I have a feeling that $(this) is undefined or not a html element

Comment: Ok you were right, it was throwing an error because I forgot to actually make it point at the class I needed it to point at, which was .tile.

But now it's not working at all, _and_ I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: can you post a snippet of the whole function / block of code?

Comment: `.mouseenter(function(){
    $( this ).velocity({
    "translateZ": "200px"
    })`

And it's supposed to modify these things:

`<a class="tile" href="assets/images/art/01.png" data-lightbox="image-1" data-title="Pixel Computer, 2016"><img src="assets/images/art/01.png"/></a>`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wfomy8u3/1/

you can check this fiddle. First of all the selected element with jquery should be the image and not the a element (since the hover/mouseenter is actually applied to the img and not the anchor).
second: you have translateX and translateY - no translateZ, also translate without " ".
Hope you will find it helpful

Comment: Thanks, adding the img in the quotation marks worked. The no translateZ thing is really weird though, seeing as it appears as an option on velocityjs.org...

Comment: yeah I know its dumb. if you want to do a "zoom in effect" heres a little thing I wrote for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/wfomy8u3/3/